# UMAP fails upon py2app build due to libllvmlite.dylib error

Tags: numba, py2app

I am freezing the GitHub distribution of the software AltAnalyze which we develop (https://github.com/nsalomonis/altanalyze). The UMAP-learn package depends on numba and llvmlite which runs fine from the source code, however, when a distribution version is built with py2app, UMAP fails with the following error:

```
File "umap/__init__.pyc", line 1, in <module>
File "umap/umap_.pyc", line 19, in <module>
File "numba/__init__.pyc", line 11, in <module>
File "numba/config.pyc", line 19, in <module>
File "llvmlite/binding/__init__.pyc", line 6, in <module>
File "llvmlite/binding/dylib.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "llvmlite/binding/ffi.pyc", line 128, in <module>
OSError: dlopen(AltAnalyze.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.dylib, 6): no suitable image found. Did find:AltAnalyze.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
```

I have tried re-installing numba and llvmlite and calling various dependent functions in the module that loads UMAP:

```
import numba
import llvmlite; from llvmlite import binding
from llvmlite.binding import *
from llvmlite.binding import ffi
from llvmlite.binding import dylib
```

But the error persists. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem.

https://req.thevirtualbrain.org/browse/TVB-2144?focusedCommentId=15056&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15056

What we do in our project, we have a *setup_mac.py*, where we fill *packages*, *includes, excludes* options for py2app.
Each entry into *packages* list is not a full-path, but only a name. At this list we added *llvmlite*, to fix exactly this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So we were able to find a work around, but it ain't pretty. 
First, we re-ran the py2app setup script with the explicit framework and packages options:

```
python build_scripts/setup_binary.py py2app --frameworks /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/libllvmlite.dylib --packages llvmlite,numba
```

This gives no longer throws the llvmlite error when running UMAP but fails with:

```
File "umap/__init__.pyc", line 9 in <module>
File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc",line 480, in get_distribution
File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc",line 356, in get_provider
File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc",line 905, in require
File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc",line 791, in resolve
DistributionNotFound: The 'umap-learn' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

This is particularly strange, since llvmlite is imported by numba from umap, but here, numba and llvmlite are imported fine... it is umap that won't import. Unable to find a clean fix, we copied the umap library directory to our software and called it directly... which worked.

We welcome a cleaner solution.